# Process two-way binding using directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this directive I use to set up some fields (within the element with the directive) to use jQuery's DatePicker. I use this directive on its own and within ng-repeat blocks too.

```
myDirectives.directive('datePickerGroup', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).find('.dateDisplay').datepicker();
        }
    };
});

<div date-picker-group="">
    <!-- Some other stuff -->
    <input ng-model="[some model]" class="dateDisplay" />
</div>
```

Now, my data model uses timestamps for all these date values. For obvious reasons, the user should see a regular date format, not a timestamp.

So, what I am trying to figure out is a way to set up a two way data bind where the binding from the model to the view uses the DatePicker's formatDate() to display a human-readable date and then when modified, the binding from the view to the model uses the same function to  translate the new human-readable date to a timestamp and save it to the model (in $scope).

So far I had been doing the following:

1) After loading the model into the controller (e.g. $scope.data), create equivalent variables where I hold the human-readable versions of the dates and use those to bind to the view date fields. So for an array of timestamps in $scope.data.stamps, I would create $scope.formattedDates.

2) When the user submits changes, then I go through those equivalent variables, re-format them to stamps and put them where they belong in the model (i.e. $scope.data).

While this works, it obviously is not ideal as it doesn't update the model directly (while other parts of the model are bound directly to parts of $scope.data). So I wonder if there is a way to set it up so that I bind to the real model variables ($scope.data.stamps in the example above) and have this re-formatting happen in either direction of the two-way data bind?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider variant with [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). On one side you have timestamp and on other date. And they uniquely corresponds:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.timestamp = 1234567890000;
});

app.directive('actsAsDate', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

           modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
             return (new Date(value)).toString();         
           });

           modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            return Date.parse(value);
          });

         }
    }
});
```

See plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/VDdmKamK8FIvq0Bf6UBv?p=preview

Good luck with AngularJS.